# Simultaneous and Pointwise Confidence Bands for GAMs

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-additive-model

I am performing a penalized B-spline regression on a simple time series of count data in R using the mgcv package. When I calculate a pointwise confidence band from the standard error of the fit based on the estimated degrees of freedom, it turns out to be slightly *wider* than the simultaneous confidence band produced by posterior simulation of the fitted GAM (as per:  [Confidence interval for GAM model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/confidence-interval-for-gam-model)). As per Wood (2006), I'm using the Bayesian posterior covariance matrix from mgcv.

Some difference may be attributable to using the t distribution for calculating the pointwise band and assuming a multivariate normal for the posterior simulation, but I had expected the latter to reflect more uncertainty about the mean response due to the multiple comparisons issue. Am I correct in assuming that approximate equivalence of the simultaneous and pointwise confidence bands is a special case, and if so, are there specific conditions required to obtain this result?

Wood, S.N. (2006) Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R. Chapman and Hall/CRC.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a error in my thinking in the simultaneous intervals blog post I linked to in the Q&A you quote here. There's been some recent discussion in the comments there.

Comment: Now I'm certain there was a flaw in my original thinking (quite what I *was* thinking escapes me now as I did know how to do the simultaneous intervals properly at the time). I have a new post up which does the simultaneous intervals in the way I had originally come across them in Ruppert, Wand, and Carroll's Semiparametric Regression book. That post is here: http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/12/15/simultaneous-interval-revisited/ I'm sorry to have caused confusion or wasted your time with that original post.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments by Gavin Simpson:

> I'm pretty sure there's a error in my thinking in the simultaneous
> intervals blog post I linked to in the Q&A you quote here. There's
> been some recent discussion in the comments there.

> Now I'm certain there was a flaw in my original thinking (quite what I
> was thinking escapes me now as I did know how to do the simultaneous
> intervals properly at the time). I have a new post up which does the
> simultaneous intervals in the way I had originally come across them in
> Ruppert, Wand, and Carroll's Semiparametric Regression book. That post
> is here: http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/12/15/simultaneous-interval-revisited/ I'm sorry to have
> caused confusion or wasted your time with that original post.