# How to extract confidence interval from mgcv GAM model?

Tags: predictive-models, fitting, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have a basic GAM model setup, with one predictor:

`fit <- gam(response ~ s(predictor, k=12), data = data, 
)`

I noticed I can easily pull out the fitted values with the `fit$fitted.values` accessor.

The documentation says the confidence intervals are computed in a bayesian manner, but I wasn't able to find them in the returned object. It seems to somehow be related to fit$hat.

I could feed the model back into predict but that just produces another regression model, does it not? I'd like to use the confidence bans from the mgcv package GAM model itself.

Comment: ¿Does the function fitted(fit) produce anything?  If so, try confint(fit). Next option is to try names(fit) and names(summary(fit)) to see what you might be able to access.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/confidence-interval-for-gam-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `fit$fitted.values` use `fitted(fit)` to access the fitted values.

`$hat` contains the leading diagonal of the hat (influence) matrix, i.e. the hat values. Again, access them using `influence()`.

No; using the `predict()` method does *not* refit the model nor produce another model. It will produce a range of predictions depending on argument `type`.

As the [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33328/1390) linked to in the comment shows, you need to generate predictions from the model over the range of `predictor` and compute a normal point-wise interval from the standard errors returned by `predict()` when `se.fit = TRUE`. If this is a GAM (i.e. using a non-Gaussian `family`) then this must be done with `type = "link"`, the default.

You can do this quickly using the `confint()` method from the **schoenberg** package, currently on *github*:

```
## install.packages("devtools")
## devtools::install_github("gavinsimpson/schoenberg")
library("schoenberg")
library("mgcv")
set.seed(2)
dat <- gamSim(1, n = 400, dist = "normal", scale = 2)
mod <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = dat, method = "REML")
##'
## point-wise interval
ci <- confint(mod, parm = "x1", type = "confidence")
head(ci)
```

This produces:

```
>     head(ci)
  smooth           x1      est        se     crit    lower    upper
1  s(x1) 0.0006632213 5.888546 0.3134611 1.959964 5.274174 6.502919
2  s(x1) 0.0056813456 5.895688 0.3045623 1.959964 5.298757 6.492619
3  s(x1) 0.0106994698 5.902830 0.2958458 1.959964 5.322983 6.482677
4  s(x1) 0.0157175940 5.909974 0.2873297 1.959964 5.346818 6.473130
5  s(x1) 0.0207357183 5.917121 0.2790332 1.959964 5.370226 6.464016
6  s(x1) 0.0257538425 5.924272 0.2709761 1.959964 5.393169 6.455376
```

If, as here, you don't provide any `newdata` it will generate new data over the range of the indicated covariate (`x1` in this case) to generate a fine enough set of values over the range of the spline to produce a nice smooth plot.

You can always provide it your data (via argument `newdata`) to generate prediction and confidence intervals for your observations.